# Toshiba L40 PSL48e does not update bios

Tags: laptop, bios, windows-vista

I have Toshiba L40 PSL48e. Also known as l40-18l and l40-15g.

It has bios version 1.6 and I need to  update it to v2.0.
However after installing the bios and acquire the files from toshiba website I can not upgrade it.

It allways comes back to v1.6: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBL3z4tuFNA&feature=emb_logo

I have found the instructions for updating the bios:

BIOS for Windows VISTA OS Installation

This BIOS is intended for use with a Windows Vista OS. Windows XP installation may NOT work properly with this BIOS.

This BIOS can ONLY be used on the following model:
PSL48*-******
PSL49*-******
PSL4A*-******
PSL4B*-******
PSL4C*-******
Procedure:-

1. Unzip BIOS file to any folder.
2. Run "UpdateBIOS.bat" in above folder on Windows screen.
3. After BIOS update is completed, the system will restart automatically.
4. While Toshiba LOGO screen is being displayed, press [F2] key to access BIOS S
   etup Menu.
5. Press [F9] key and choose "Yes". Press [F10] key and choose "Yes".
6. BIOS update will be completed.

[Points to be noted for rewrite BIOS]
Please note before updating the BIOS of your notebook computer:
* Flashing of wrong BIOS may permanently damage your notebook. Please contact TG
SC or your nearest Toshiba Mobile Computing Partner for more detail.
* AC adaptor must be used in the upgrade process.
* The machine must be in BOOT mode, not Resume mode.
* Any power on passwords must be disabled.
* All PCMCIA cards must be removed from the system prior to upgrading the BIOS.
* The notebook computer must not be attached to any type of docking device.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be how your computer shuts down prior to reboot: "The machine must be in BOOT mode, not Resume mode." You may have [Windows *Fast Startup*](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup) enabled, or allow Hibernation.

To ensure complete shutdown prior to rebooting,

- In BIOS/UEFI, disable *Fast Startup*.
- Reboot.
- Shut down the computer from the command line. Open a CMD prompt as Administrator by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>, typing `cmd`, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, and accepting the UAC dialog.
- Enter the following lines, one at a time, to shut down, deleting *hyberfil.sys*.

  `powercfg -h off`

  `shutdown /s /t 0`
- After that, boot again, and try following the update instructions.

BTW, thank you for providing good diagnostic information, including the video. Hopefully, this will help.

Comment: today we will try again and we will see. I also think it might be because of vista sp3, maybe it has to be sp1.

Comment: BTW, Why Vista? It was quickly supplanted by 7, 8, and 10. and is no longer supported. There are no security updates nor new drivers, and some new apps no longer work under Vista.

Comment: Because the bios update was lauched for vista.
However after everything I still couldn't make it work.

Comment: any other ideas?

Comment: Only to contact Toshiba Support, https://www.toshiba.com/tai/support.jsp